# Does playa support other languages? (Arabic)

Tags: playa, entries, ee

I'm using playa in one of my channel fields and I tried to publish entries in Arabic, but the Arabic entry doesn't render at all on the home page. Do I need to add something to this code in order to enable the Arabic language? I checked the documentation, and unfortunately  it doesn't mention anything about the use of other languages.

```
  <span class="venue">{venue:ul}</span>
```

Comment: Is it only the play field that doesn't get rendered or no content at all?

Comment: when I publish english in the same field, it seems to be working fine, but when I publish Arabic content in the same field, the content doesn't appear on the page at all. It's empty